# Split POST array into multiple variables

Tags: php, jquery

I'm coding a form right now using jQuery .post and the file responsible for processing has the code:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Which returns the following dynamic output:

```
Array ( [data] => capacity=50-1000+people&bookingdate=17%2F04%2F2012&grade=1+star )
```

I am trying to split up this array into three variables namely **capacity**, **booking date** and **grade** but don't really know how to. Any idea how? I've tried using **echo $_POST["capacity"];** but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#postData").click(function() {
        $("#last-step").hide(600);


       $.post('resources/process2.php', { data: $("#task5_booking").serialize() }, function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
      });


        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

which is working with the following form:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/93/

Comment: Looks like you're double URL encoding the data. While it's easy to answer your question literally, the real problem seems to be in how you're POSTing the data from the jQuery side.

Comment: i guess it will be muck better to encode your data into json in js and then decode in the server side

Comment: showing the jQuery side will a good idea.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the jQuery as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should change this line:

```
$.post('resources/process2.php', { data: $("#task5_booking").serialize() }, function(data) {
```

To

```
$.post('resources/process2.php', $("#task5_booking").serialize(), function(data) {
```

Notice that I changed the second parameter from an object literal to a (url-encoded) string. This posts each variable in your form as a separate variable (as if it were posted directly). On the server side, each variable should be available separately inside `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Something like:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'] , $output);

$capacity = $output['capacity'];
$bookingdate = $output['bookingdate'];
$grade = $output['grade'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use explode for this.

```
$data = array();  // A array to store the extracted value
$temp = explode("&", $data); // First of all explode by "&" to get the each piece
foreach($temp as $tval) {
   $t = explode('=', $tval); // Next explode by "=" to get the index and value
   $data[$t[0]] = $t[1];  //Add them to the array
}
```

Another alternative is to use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$data = array();
parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);
```

After this all the values will be mapped to the `$data`